# Bash: sort csv file by first 4 columns

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, csv

I have a csv file with fields delimited by ";". There are 8 fields, and I want to sort my data by the first 4 columns, in increasing order (first sort by column 1, then column 2, etc)

How I can do this from a command line in linux?

I tried with open office, but it only lets me select 3 columns.

EDIT: among the fields on which I want to sort my data, three fields contain strings with numerical values, one only strings. How can I specify this with the `sort` command?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
sort -t\; -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n test.txt
```

eg:

```
1;2;100;4
1;2;3;4
10;1;2;3
9;1;2;3

> sort -t\; -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n temp3
1;2;3;4
1;2;100;4
9;1;2;3
10;1;2;3
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the meaning of `1,1n` here?

Comment: Oh ok. So, say that field 3 contains strings, I will do `-k 3,3d` to sort by dictionary order, right?

Answer (score 9):

`sort -k` will allow you to define the sort key. From `man sort`:

```
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
       start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line).
```

So

```
$ sort -t\; -k1,4
```

should do it. Note that I've escaped the semi-colon, otherwise the shell will interpret it as an end-of-statement.

Comment: Thanks. Does `sort` allow also to specify for each field whether I want to sort numerically or alphabetically? (see my last edit)