# How to sort a CSV file with HEX numbers?

Tags: bash, sorting, csv, hex

I'm having a blonde moment and can't seem to get my head around it, but I have a csv file (sample below) in which I would like to sort the rows out by the first value in the row - hexa-numerically (from small to large)

```
570e2e5c,1460539517,SOM3-String-123,08-5a-0c-59
570e2e81,1460539520,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e87,1460539521,SOM3-String-123,09-5e-6b-22
570e2e5e,1460539518,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e90,1460539522,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e95,1460539523,SOM3-String-123,09-00-67-22
570e2e60,1460539519,SOM3-String-123,09-00-68-22
```

**Q:** How can I sort out with BASH script a csv files rows by the rows first element which is hexadecimal?

**Addendum:**

So I convert the hex strings into a dec strings with this code:

```
IFS=','
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 
do 

f1_upper_case=`echo "$f1" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`
f1_dec=$((16#$f1_upper_case))
echo "$f1_dec,$f2,$f3,$f4" >>$csv_temp 

done < $csv
```

I will try to sort by `$f1_dec` in the csv file.

Comment: For sorting using just the first element, you should be able to adapt the code easily from [Bash - sort CSV file by first four columns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11934809/62576). Your hex values should sort fine without any conversion.

Comment: @KenWhite Why doesn't it matter? Wouldn't `0xf`, which is smaller than `0xaf`, get sorted the wrong way around? I guess it depends on padding, i.e., the exact format of the hex numbers.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Please don't link to the files, put a representative excerpt of them into the question itself.

Comment: Looks like they're all the same width, so you can just sort lexically.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ok. But why the downvote :/

Comment: That wasn't my downvote - and if you want to improve your question further, show what you've tried so far and how it didn't work for you.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139801/sort-by-hex-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the strings all have the same number of digits and the same letter case, as is true in your sample data, you can just sort as-is. The default lexical sort will put them in the right order because the hex digits 0-9a-f occur in that order in standard character sets.

If you might have some numbers with different numbers of digits, or if you have mixed upper and lower case on the alphabetic digits, then your best bet is probably to convert to decimal, sort numerically, and convert back. If you have the GNU version of awk, you can use it to do the conversion:

```
awk -v{,O}FS=, '{$1=strtonum("0x"$1)}1' $filename | 
    sort -t, -n -k1,1 |
    awk -v{,O}FS=, '{$1=sprintf("%x",$1)}1' >$new_filename
```

Run on your sample input, I get this output:

```
570e2e5c,1460539517,SOM3-String-123,08-5a-0c-59
570e2e5e,1460539518,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e60,1460539519,SOM3-String-123,09-00-68-22
570e2e81,1460539520,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e87,1460539521,SOM3-String-123,09-5e-6b-22
570e2e90,1460539522,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e95,1460539523,SOM3-String-123,09-00-67-22
```

Explanation:

`-v name=value` tells `awk` to set a variable that will exist in the context of the program; this is a handy way to inject values without having to deal with the quoting complexities that accompany string interpolation into code. But some variable names are special; `FS` tells `awk` what (F)ield (S)eparator to use to split the input lines into fields, and `OFS` tells it what (O)utput field separator to use when printing lines back out. The `-v{,O}FS=,` sequence is just a shortcut to set both variables to the same value; it gets expanded by the shell's brace-expansion into `-vFS=, -vOFS=,`. So within the awk program, each line will be pre-split on commas into fields, with the individual field values in the variables `$1`, `$2`, and so on. When those variables are changed, they will be joined back together with commas when printed back out.

The code in the string passed to `awk` after the `-v` options is the `awk` program to run. Such a program is a sequence of (condition, block) pairs; each condition is checked against each line of input, and then the block is evaluated if the condition is true. If a block appears without a condition, it is run on every line; if a condition appears without a block, it causes the current line – or the fields of the current line joined by OFS, if other blocks have made modifications – to be printed out.

The programs above use both defaults; each starts with a code block that has no condition, so it is run on every line, and ends with a condition that has no code block: 1, which is always true, so every line is printed back out after the code block has made its changes.

The first `awk` program uses the `strtonum` function to convert the first field to decimal. This is why this solution only works in GNU awk; BSD awk (which is also the one that ships on macOS) does not have `strtonum`. We have to prepend "0x" to the field value so that `strtonum` will know to treat it as hexadecimal, but once it is a numeric value, it will be printed out as decimal. So the output of the `awk` is the same as the input except with the first field converted to decimal.

We feed that to `sort`, tell it to sort numerically (`-n`) by that first (`-k1,1`) comma-separated (`-t,`) field, and then feed the sorted output into the second `awk`, which uses the `sprintf` function to convert the numeric first field back to hex.

Comment: could you kindly explain how this code works? i.e what -vOFS and -F strtonum, for myself and everyone to understand please? Also where do i feed the `$csv` file. Also the first column is a timestamp in HEX different to the timestamp in second column. Could you kindly  include this in a while read loop so I can better understand!

Comment: `-vOFS=`, sets the "OFS" variable to a comma. OFS is the "output field separator", and so setting this to a comma causes the output fields to be delimited as such. The `-F,` sets the input field delimiter to a comma, and the `strtonum("0x"$1)` converts a string to a number. The 0x part is added so that `strtonum` interprets the string as a hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 2):

Input:

```
$ cat /tmp/so36636125.txt 
570e2e5c,1460539517,SOM3-String-123,08-5a-0c-59
570e2e81,1460539520,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e87,1460539521,SOM3-String-123,09-5e-6b-22
570e2e5e,1460539518,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e90,1460539522,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e95,1460539523,SOM3-String-123,09-00-67-22
570e2e60,1460539519,SOM3-String-123,09-00-68-22
```

Transformation one liner:

```
$ awk '{ dec = sprintf("%d", "0x" $1); print dec " "  $0 }' /tmp/so36636125.txt | sort -n -k 1 | cut -f2- -d' '
570e2e5c,1460539517,SOM3-String-123,08-5a-0c-59
570e2e5e,1460539518,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e60,1460539519,SOM3-String-123,09-00-68-22
570e2e81,1460539520,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e87,1460539521,SOM3-String-123,09-5e-6b-22
570e2e90,1460539522,SOM3-String-123,08-00-0c-59
570e2e95,1460539523,SOM3-String-123,09-00-67-22

$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
```

Explanation:

- `awk` adds a new first column as the decimal representation of the
  hex number
- `sort` numerically on first column
- `cut` removes the first
  column